# Convert .pps to .mp4

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Can a script be created that would convert a .pps file to .mp4?
I know that .pps is the older slideshow format but we are still using an older version of PowerPoint to play the slideshow.
The powerpoint slideshow file does not contain any embedded videos, just individual timings and actions in each slide.

Comment: Does [Save a presentation as a movie file or MP4 - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-presentation-as-a-movie-file-or-mp4-4e1ebcc1-f46b-47b6-922a-bac76c4a5691) answer your question?

Comment: Or [How to Convert Powerpoint to MP4 (with Pictures) - wikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Powerpoint-to-MP4)?

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint since version 2016 supports exporting to MP4.

To open a `.pps` file in PowerPoint, all you have to do is rename the
file to `.ppt` and it will open automatically in PowerPoint when executed.
Old formats are supported. Without the rename operation, PowerPoint
will only play the presentation.

The methods for exporting are described in the links inside the
comments below your post.

Comment: Thanks for response, I know that within PowerPoint we can export out to .mp4 format. We play the .m4 on a TV screen in our church vestibule and post to our church YouTube channel. The church secretary edits and updates the slideshow but is not involved in creating the .mp4 and posting. I would like to have a script to simplify the process for our secretary.

Comment: There are websites that will do that freely, although sound will probably be lost. A product is [Free PPT to DVD Converter](https://www.digitalofficepro.com/powerpoint/ppt-to-dvd-lite.html), although I don't know how well it works. Other products are usually commercial. To create yourself a batch product that does it will probably need VBA, requiring some learning curve.

Comment: Would prefer to stay away from online resource (free or paid). Yes, creating a batch will be a big learning curve for me. I am only a little familiar with creating cmd scripts. I use several batch routines with task scheduler to automate processes such as file backups from our church office computer using robocopy. I get the sense that creating a script to do what I would like for the converting of .pps to .mp4 could be a bit complicated. Perhaps I need to forget that idea and just go with manual step of using PowerPoint to export to .mp4.

Comment: You could use a macro product such as AutoHotKey to automate renaming, launching PowerPoint, clicking the menus and starting the export. But this can go wrong unexpectedly, so I wouldn't recommend it for simple users that could get lost here.

Answer (score 0):

This page on my PPT FAQ site explains how to use a few lines of VBA code to export your presentation to video:

https://pptfaq.com/FAQ01261-Video-export-your-way.htm

Note: You can either rename your PPS to PPT if you want to open it by doubleclicking the file's icon, or you can start PowerPoint, choose File | Open then browse to the PPS file to open it in normal/editing view.

You can't rename PPSX files to PPTX and expect them to work this way; you MUST use File | Open to open them in normal view.